# Magento 2 forgot password doesn't check email exist exist or not

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.4

Magento 2 **forgot password** doesn't check email exist or not. It gives the message

> If there is an account associated with xxxx@xxxx.com you will receive
>   an email with a link to reset your password.

It should give an error message if email not exist.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be security risk as any one can check if some user have account on the website or not . 
Then he just have to guess a password . So message should be always success .

If you want to change it , you can modify the logic in 
**magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php**in `initiatePasswordReset` method where customer is loaded . you can check if customer exists and throw error like

```
$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    __('The email address is does not exist. Verify the email address and try again.')
```

But **i would strongly suggest not to change this logic as that would be security flaw**

Comment: You are right, that would be a security risk.